# how to query the same columns from all tables in the schema with given criteria in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database

I have a database "warehouse" including tables of daily inventory records, one table for each day.

Now, I need to check the historic change of the inventory level. The output will print the inventory of each day given certain criteria.

I am not sure how to describe it, so I created a simplified sample of the schema, its tables and the expected output.

The schema "warehouse" has a list of tables:

[image]

Each table contains the same columns for product ID and inventory, below is table 101

[image]

For each table, I need to do a query:
select count(*) as num_of_product_with_inventory from [table name]. After I have the query result from each table, I should have an output like in below:

[image]

Can anyone show me how the query should look like to get the final output? I only know the basic queries and have no clue how to put these together. Thank you!

Comment: What do the rows in the warehouse table represent? It seems like a bad idea to have potentially hundreds of separate tables with identical schemas.

Comment: yeah throw out this data model. Lost my confidence completely at the end of the first sentence.

Comment: @Caius those are the list of tables in the schema warehouse, we have table, 101, 102, 103, etc....

Answer (score 0):

The data model you have is making your work harder than it should be.
If you must keep it, you will need to use a stored procedure or do the loop in your code (not in sql).

But you should really do is change the data model.
It is not recommended at all to create a table per day!

It's a mix of **DATA** with **METADATA**. The table structure should represent different types of data that you store, while the fact that you had different inventory on date X vs date Y should be in your data.

So, recommend to create one table with columns `date`, `product_id` and `warehouse_inventory`. If it gets too big, you can partition it by date (week/month/..). Then you can easily get your data with something like:

```
SELECT date, count(*) AS num_of_products_with_inventory
FROM daily_inventory i
WHERE i.date BETWEEN '<some date>' and '<some date>'
GROUP BY date
```

Comment: @Caius@Galz@Drew Thank you all for the suggestion, that is the data model I have right now which i dont have access to make changes.

Comment: @Zoey - so, except mysql, what else can you work with? My suggestion would be to run a query on the schema to get all table names, and then in your code, loop over the tables to get the count one at a time.